# Resizing an Image smaller just cuts off the edge instead

Tags: c#, image, resize, crop

This is all in C#:

I am using this code to resize an image:

```
_image = (Image)new Bitmap(_refImage, _width, _height);
```

_refImage is just a reference image, identical to the original image so that resolution is not messed up if I resize multiple times.

This code works fine if I make the image bigger, it stretches it as it is supposed to.

However if I make the image smaller, then it just cuts off the edge instead.

I am just resizing the width as I want just the width to change.

Comment: Will [this](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2003/05/29/Resize-Image-in-C/) work?

Comment: No it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a link which will probably work: [Here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/c-resize-image-while). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, worked really well. I needed to use Image.GetThumbNailImage and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Scales to within given boundaries - Aspect ratio is kept. High Quality Bi-Cubic interpolation is used.
        /// If boundary is larger than the image, then image is scaled up; if smaller, it is scaled down.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="originalImg">Image: Image to scale</param>
        /// <param name="width">Int: Restriction on width for output size. Must be greater than zero</param>
        /// <param name="height">Int: Restriction on height for output size. Must be greater than zero</param>
        /// <param name="backgroundColour">Color: Colour to shade background behind image</param>
        /// <returns>Image: Scaled Image</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">[ArgumentException] Boundary dimensions must exceed zero</exception>
        public static Image ScaleToFit(Image originalImg, int width, int height, Color backgroundColour)
        {
            if (originalImg == null) return null;
            if (width < 1 || height < 1) throw new ArgumentException("ScaleToFit: Boundary dimensions must exceed zero.");

            var destX = 0;
            var destY = 0;
            float nPercent;

            var nPercentW = (width / (float)originalImg.Width);
            var nPercentH = (height / (float)originalImg.Height);
            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            {
                nPercent = nPercentH;
                destX = Convert.ToInt16((width - (originalImg.Width * nPercent)) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                nPercent = nPercentW;
                destY = Convert.ToInt16((height - (originalImg.Height * nPercent)) / 2);
            }

            var destWidth = (int)(originalImg.Width * nPercent);
            var destHeight = (int)(originalImg.Height * nPercent);

            var bmPhoto = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmPhoto.SetResolution(originalImg.HorizontalResolution, originalImg.VerticalResolution);

            var grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
            grPhoto.Clear(backgroundColour);
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            grPhoto.DrawImage(originalImg,
                new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImg.Width, originalImg.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            grPhoto.Dispose();
            return bmPhoto;
        }
```

Note: This keeps the aspect ratio, you can change that if you want to skew it easily enough.